# Calling a long running web service - get details of the request in the continuation

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

Say I have something like the following code:

```
Dim serviceTasks As New List(Of Task)()

serviceTasks.Add(Task(Of XmlElement).Factory.FromAsync(AddressOf proxy.BeginLongRunningService, _
                                                                 AddressOf proxy.EndLongRunningService, _
                                                                 serviceInput, _
                                                                 proxy) _
                                    .ContinueWith(Sub(antecedent) HandleServiceReturn(antecedent)))
```

And my continuation:

```
private sub HandleServiceReturn(antecedant As Task(Of XmlElement))

   'Do stuff with our result here
    dim data = antecedant.result

end sub
```

Where my 'serviceInput' object is an XML document being passed to a long running web service.  I create groups of these tasks and run them asynchronously and all is fine until I hit an error in the web service call.  In this case, it would be useful to be able to access the 'request' parameters that were sent to the service in my continuation, as the result is just an exception.

I'm fairly new to the TPL, and I was wondering if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value of the serviceInput variable on to your continuation like so:

```
serviceTasks.Add(Task(Of XmlElement).Factory.FromAsync(AddressOf proxy.BeginLongRunningService, _  
                                                       AddressOf proxy.EndLongRunningService, _  
                                                       serviceInput, _  
                                                       proxy) _  
                             .ContinueWith(Sub(antecedent) HandleServiceReturn(serviceInput, antecedent)))

private sub HandleServiceReturn(input As XmlDocument, antecedant As Task(Of XmlElement))
```